# Implicitly convert to reference

Tags: c++

I have:

```
struct vec {
    __m128 m128;
    inline vec(__m128 m128) : m128(m128) {
    }
}
```

so now `__m128` can implicitly convert to `vec`, but when I use it, as in:

```
void doStuff(vec &v) { *stuff be doing* }
doStuff( _mm_set1_ps(1.0f)); //mm_set_ps returns __m128
```

I get an error saying:

> Can't convert from __m128 to &vec

so what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: You can't take a non-const ref to a temporary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`doStuff` takes in a reference to a non-const `vec`. Non-const references cannot bind to rvalues like the result of a function call.

If you need to modify `v` inside `doStuff`, then store the result of `_mm_set1_ps(1.0f)` in an intermediate variable, then call with that:

```
vec v = _mm_set1_ps(1.0f);
doStuff(v);
```

If you don't need to modify `v`, change `doStuff` to take its argument by reference-to-const:

```
void doStuff(const vec &v) { /*stuff doing*/ }
```

Comment: why reference to const necessary?

Comment: @Ragdoll reference to const may bind to an rvalue

Comment: @Ragdoll Because in theory, you're not supposed to modify temporaries :)